# Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to web development and I am trying to upload a D3-based JS visualization to a Weebly domain. I have uploaded all required files to my Weebly site and referenced them properly in the JavaScript, but keep getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined error on this line:

```
d3.csv("http://subdomain.weebly.com/files/theme/force.csv", function(error, links) {
```

Where I try to call d3 to load in a CSV file for my visualization. I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

Also, I loaded d3 (hosted locally) into the JS with this line:

```
<script src="http://subdomain.weebly.com/files/theme/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and also tried to link to d3 remotely, but still get the same error.

This has me very confused because everything works fine on my localhost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

insert the following into your html

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you think this solves the question if the locally hosted version also didn't work?

Comment: I assumed it's an issue with the location of the file on his machine. Also, he mentions that he also tried to link to the file remotely with no luck but doesn't have that code snippet. This allows him to link to the file remotely.

Comment: SailorLeroy, I originally used that line of code before trying to locally host D3. It also did not work. I wonder if it isn't something with Weebly that doesn't allow loading your own script?

Comment: Hello All, I ended up just reverting to a pre-existing theme in Weebly instead of trying to create my own custom theme. I don't know what my problem is, but I ended up being able to just re-upload my force.csv file to the new theme's folder, and copy/paste my JS into a custom HTML script box in the GUI web editor.

Thank you for your answers, I'll edit this post if I ever figure out exactly what went wrong!

Comment: D3 utilizes UTF-8 characters in its code, which mrans that you can do **one of three things**:

You can set your document to UTF-8:
`<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset="utf-8">`.

Or you can set tha charset of the script to UTF-8:
`<script charset="utf-8 src="d3.js"></script>`.

Or you can use the minified script, which shouldn't have any UTF-8 characters in it:
`<script src="d3.min.js"></script>`.

@aschaefer's script is OK, the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. It got solved after I replaced the link I was using  with the one said above by @Ihoworko 
which is this