# Getting error of "D3-tree", while using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a tree using `Vue` and the `dTree` js library ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-dtree/v/0.3.1)).

I installed the library by using: `npm i d3-dtree`..

Then I wrote the following script:

```
<template>
    <div id="tree"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import dTree from 'd3-dtree/dist/dTree.js';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';

    Vue.use(VueResource);

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                treeData: [{
                  "name": "Niclas Superlongsurname",
                  "class": "man",
                  "textClass": "emphasis",
                  "marriages": [{
                    "spouse": {
                      "name": "Iliana",
                      "class": "woman",
                      "extra": {
                        "nickname": "Illi"
                      }
                    },
                    "children": [{
                      "name": "James",
                      "class": "man",
                      "marriages": [{
                        "spouse": {
                          "name": "Alexandra",
                          "class": "woman"
                        },
                        "children": [{
                          "name": "Eric",
                          "class": "man",
                          "marriages": [{
                            "spouse": {
                              "name": "Eva",
                              "class": "woman"
                            }
                          }]
                        }, {
                          "name": "Jane",
                          "class": "woman"
                        }, {
                          "name": "Jasper",
                          "class": "man"
                        }, {
                          "name": "Emma",
                          "class": "woman"
                        }, {
                          "name": "Julia",
                          "class": "woman"
                        }, {
                          "name": "Jessica",
                          "class": "woman"
                        }]
                      }]
                    }]
                  }]
                }]
            }
        },

        mounted: function() {
            dTree.init(this.treeData, {
                target: "#tree",
                debug: true,
                height: 800,
                width: 1200,
                callbacks: {
                    nodeClick: function(name, extra) {
                    console.log(name);
                    }
                }
            });
        },

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
     div {
             margin: auto 0;
              width: 100%;
     }
 </style>
```

After running the script, I get the following error:

> Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: d3 is not defined"

(Also tried to move the method to `created()`).

Tried to find a solution in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291823/uncaught-referenceerror-d3-is-not-defined), but it didn't solve the problem.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you omitted your `created` hook / function? That's where it says the error is

Comment: @Phil, thank you for noticing, I meant `mounted` (but I also tried to move the method to `created`. Please see my small edit.

Comment: You aren't using `d3` anywhere in your `mounted` hook. Are you sure this error message is referring to this component?

Comment: @Phil I know that `dtree` (link in the thread) is using the `d3`. So I guess its comes from there.